# IE 11 on Windows 7 VS IE 11 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

Could anyone please detail the difference between IE 11 on windows 7 and IE 11 on windows 10.

My organization has done lot of testing while moving from IE 8 to IE 11 on windows 7 and now they want to upgrade to windows 10.

However before moving to Win 10, they want to be sure that IE11 on Win 10 is exactly same as IE 11 on Windows 7.

I am not able to find any article on Microsoft website, which explains it.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards

Comment: 32 or 64-bit IE?

Comment: Thanks,IE version 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine they render the page in the same way (CSS etc.) but there are some security changes.

On [Windows 8 and later](https://securityintelligence.com/internet-explorer-ie-10-enhanced-protected-mode-epm-sandbox-research/) IE can run in a [AppContainer sandbox](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/03/23/understanding-enhanced-protected-mode/). [Enhanced Protected Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can cause issues with 3rd-party browser extensions [and local files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/06/19/enhanced-protected-mode-and-local-files/). EPM is optional and can be turned on/off.

There are also [changes at the network level](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/08/01/networking-improvements-in-ie10-and-windows-8/) and backend storage.

If you rely on 3rd-party extensions or local file/localhost access you might want to do some testing before migrating, if not then I don't see any real showstoppers.

Answer (score 1):

I noted this particular difference concerning the HTTP header Content-Disposition for file downloads.

Java example to instruct the browser to use fileName as its local file name:

```
String fileName="TheFileNameIWant.xyz";
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"";
```

- IE 11 on Win 7 ignores the file name from Content-Dispsition and proposes part of the download URL instead (looks strange)
- IE11 on Win 10 proposes the desired file name (as other browsers do)

However I found out that the behaviour varies across IE 11 browser versions.
It fails as described above on version 11.0.9600.18893 (IE and Win7 both 64 Bit) but works with version 11.0.9600.17691 (IE and Win 7 both 64Bit).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed another change. IE in Windows 10 supports Math.sign and other operations.
Windows 7's doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Found some differences between IE11 on Windows 10 and 8.1

Website works fine on 10, but not 8.1. Look like being something to do with the type of object returned by jQuery.ajax parsing JSON.

We use babel, which polyfills array.entries(), but the (from JSON) object doesn't have it.